# HostKeyAlgorithms in sshd config on debian - daemon reload fail

Tags: ssh, debian, daemon

I have a Debian Jessie Server and I would like to verify the fingerprint of the ssh keys on the server about a DNS SSHFP record. This works fine, but if a client connect over ssh to the server, the server provide the `ssh-ecdsa` algorithm. I'd like to configure the ssh daemon that only ssh-ed25519 and `ssh-rsa`  are the supported algorithms. For Ubuntu 16.04 I works with the ssh config key `HostKeyAlgorithms` but if I use this key on Debian, I can't start the daemon.

Why the daemon don't support this configure key or must I use an other configure key to support only ssh-ed25519 and ssh-rsa algorithms?

Here my sshd_config

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
HostKey         /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey         /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey         /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey         /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#HostKeyAlgorithms  ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
LoginGraceTime      120
LogLevel                INFO
MaxAuthTries        10
MaxSessions     5
PasswordAuthentication  no
PermitEmptyPasswords    no
PermitRootLogin     without-password
Port            22
PrintMotd               no
PrintLastLog        no
Protocol        2
RSAAuthentication   no
PubkeyAuthentication    yes
ServerKeyBits       4096
StrictModes     yes
SyslogFacility          AUTH
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
Subsystem       sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
TCPKeepAlive        yes
UsePAM          no
UsePrivilegeSeparation  yes
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo sshd -T`? This option might not be implemented in the *Debian* ...

Comment: I get an configuration output like this:

port 22
protocol 2
addressfamily any
listenaddress 0.0.0.0:22
listenaddress [::]:22
usepam 0
serverkeybits 4096
logingracetime 120

..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HostKeyAlgorithms` is [not implemented in OpenSSH 6.7p1](https://anonscm.debian.org/git/pkg-ssh/openssh.git/tree/servconf.c?h=jessie), which is available in Debian Jessie.

> I'd like to configure the ssh daemon that only ssh-ed25519 and ssh-rsa are the supported algorithms

If you remove the respective key from the configuration `HostKey`, it will not be offered by the server (the following lines):

```
HostKey         /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey         /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

Comment: I comment the keys ecdsa and dsa in. The Server provide now only rsa and ed25519, but now I can't verify the HostKeyFingerprints. This Question is a new Thread.